# Would airdropped kinetic projectiles be useful against medieval armies?

Tags: warfare, medieval, metals, aircraft, kinetic-weapons

In my world, there exists giant eagles kind of similar to the ones in LOTR. These eagles are large enough to ride and are domesticated.

As a result, people have been using this giant eagles in warfare. First, they have been used as scouts. Later on they were used as transports. One day, somebody got the idea of collecting a huge number of rocks and dropping them from the eagles. This was similar to [Lazy Dog Bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_Dog_(bomb)) used in WW2. The eagles fly 1 mile up in the sky at a speed of 120 kilometers per hour.

**Pertinent Information**:
These giant eagles can carry up to 500 kilograms of weight, can fly for up to 6 hours at a full load, are as durable as a warhorse, and are as rare as elephants.

The enemies are standard late medieval Western Europeans fighting in the open plains. Typical enemy forces comprise  lightly armored pikemen/archers and heavily armored knights. No other species.

**Question**:
Would it be feasible for a country with late medieval-era technology to make a lot of kinetic projectiles, such as flechettes, for use as an effective weapon against contemporary militaries?

Comment: Useful is entirely dependent upon context. Who are they fighting, what are their capabilities, what strategic, operational, and tactical outcomes are both forces expecting to achieve. In addition to not providing essential context to answer this question in an objective manner, you also have additional questions in the body of your post. We have a strict 1question per post policy.

Comment: Also, the lifting capacity of the eagles is important.  "Big enough to ride" is fine, but "big enough to ride and also possessed of an enormous cargo capacity" generally requires engines.

Comment: I concur with the VTC in that you need some extra detail. In particular, who are they using these projectiles against? Unarmoured or lightly armoured warriors,  herd beasts, closely bunched marching columns --- those would make easy prey. Trolls, heavily armoured Dwarves, widely dispersed or well armoured warriors would not be much affected. The WP article you cite details how useful these things are. Making the things is trivially easy --- cast lead, cast bronze, wrought iron, ceramic encased metal. Loads of possibilities. I think if you focused on the enemy (cont)

Comment: (cont) and clarified some questions about the capacity of the eagles themselves, you'd have a good question. I'd happily vote to reopen it when that's done! Otherwise, I think you've already answered your own question!

Comment: Disagree with the VTC, the question as asked, is entirely understandable and reasonable. Going further and he risks violating other rules. 
To the OP, google Plumbata, or war darts. There is a youtube where a gent bundles a crapload of war darts and launches the bundle with a trebuchet. About the same effect.

Comment: @Gillgamesh --- It is understandable and reasonable as written --- but as written is not a WB question. As written, it's already been answered by the OP with the cited WP article! At best, this query has worldbuilding potential; at worst, it's a let's me google that for you waste of time because oh gee you already googled it.

Comment: As far as I see, in order of importance, it would be best if we knew : Which medieval period (it determines armor quality)? Are they fighting in a medievalish Europe, geography wise (@elemtilas Forests size is a big difference between WW2 and medieval bombardments)? Only against normal troops or troops with eagles, too?  How much darts can each eagle carry (accounting encumbrance and pure weight), and how far can they go loaded before needing to land?

Comment: And to focus the question... Don't ask about ammo economy right now : that's the topic of strategy which is quite different. You can (and I guess it will be interesting) to wonder how much ammo you can craft later on, but I think you'll need first to know how much you'll need to throw at them to be effective x).

Comment: No idea why this was closed it's easy to answer. Yes, these eagles would still be useful even today

Comment: @elemtilas the opposing military would be standard medieval human military. That would just be lightly armored pikemen/archers and heavily armored knights. No other species.

Comment: @Kilisi Not as easy as it seems : if your eagles can only carry a few darts, then it's not probably going to be very efficient regarding the cost of feeding such huge birds, maintaining equipment and training men would be. Today, they would be a waste of resources as AA is just too fast and far-ranged for them.

Comment: @Tortliena most of the World don't have AA. So they'd have uses without too much need of finding some. In ancient days they'd have a lot more uses as every stone they dropped is a free shot and walls and night aren't a barrier

Comment: In fact, a 2kg feathered spear dropped from 1000ft would smash any single human, armored or not, if it would hit. Flechettes aren't useful as they are small (light) and their speed won't be as fast. Better drop lead bombs than them. VS modern tanks - no, such eagles would be shot down with AA machine guns, as well as be impenetrable to falling objects to a degree that allows survival.

Comment: There was never a "standard late medieval Western European" fighting force. Battles aren't normally fought in an open field against an equal point cost of an opponent's force. They're fought to accomplish some operational goal, in service of some larger strategic goal. Your military needs are going to be different depending on both, as well as the opportunity costs associated with using this novel weapon system. How is the opposing force organized and armed? How large is it. How large and how well is the eagle supported force organized and armed.

Comment: @elemtilas Considering edit version #3. How can this question be answered? Which country? Exactly which year? Was the country shown how to make the bomb and we're simply asking if it can only be manufactured at that tech level? Is ITM_Coder asking for permission to use the idea? Or, worse, is he/she asking if the idea is *believable?* Is it possible to remove the "effective" qualifier since that's 100% story-based? Is the bird carrying one 500# bomb or 25 20# bombs or something else? What does "a lot" mean? ITM... What, ***exactly and specifically*** is the problem?

Comment: @Elemtilas good edit, but I'm not sure asking about flechette production match the question's current content :/ : most of the given  data are useful during the use, while this kind of question would require data *before* battle on economy and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before heavy industry, iron was too valuable and expensive to be used to create thousands of flechettes to airdrop on an enemy. Besides, they would have to be hand forged. When demolishing houses, people would recover the forged nails, because they were that expensive.

So. What did medieval people drop on enemies from above? They didn't have eagles, but they did have fortifications, and anyone trying to attack them with a ladder would receive:

- Heavy rocks
- Boiling water
- Superheated sand

The common denominator for all these is that they're very cheap, so you can store and drop a lot of it. Sand can be heated way above 100°C without boiling, and it gets inside the armor. Receiving a bucket of sand at 500-800°C must be a most unpleasing experience.

Then, the more expensive stuff:

- Arrows
- [Quicklime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxide#Weapon)

Really expensive stuff, like petrol, sulfur, oil, etc, was not actually used much.

Hot stuff does not apply in your case: if the eagle flies high enough to be safe from archers, anything dropped would cool on the way down. So I see two options:

- Chemical weapons

The flying beast carries a bag of chemicals, most likely quicklime since it was widely available at the time and not that expensive. The rider opens it by pulling a rope and undoing a knot, and it is dispersed in a cloud of blinding death over the enemies.

- Incendiary

Your enemies sleep at night, probably in a camp, and tents are quite flammable. You would need a barrel of flammable liquid, and a device to ignite it as it comes out. Note the commonly available oils at the time, vegetable oil and animal fat, are not flammable unless they're [boiling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4JUQaLHriU&t=5m41s). Then you can have a rain of flammable liquid. This can also be used to attack cities or fortifications.

Firebombs are also a possibility, but these need a means of ignition, which would be tricky. A man riding a flying beast would have little success with a lighter, because of the wind.

All of these are extremely dangerous for the beast and the rider, of course.

Comment: How do you heat water or sand up there? Do you make a campfire on the eagle?

Comment: You don't, that's why I said it wouldn't apply

Comment: +1, but might be worth saying explicitly why it doesn't apply, that even if the boiling water / heated sand was lifted from a forward base only a mile or so from the battlefield that it would cool very rapidly to be only mildly warm if dropped from a height sufficient to make the rare / valuable eagle safe from anti-air-archery.